# How to setup a cellphone proxy for international calls?

Tags: networking, proxy, phone

I'm currently in **country-A**. I have a physical working cell phone(**cellphone-B**) in **country-B**
I want to call a friend who is in **country-B**, i want my **cellphone-B** to ring him, so that he'd think i'm in **country-B**.
I need the call from **cellphone-A** to **cellphone-B** to be done through the internet(UDP socket connection), but a normal phone call from **cellphone-B** to my friend.

I'm a software engineer, I develop apps on Android and iOS, I have a fair knowledge in networks, I can setup a server if needed.

How can I do this?

Comment: You're likely looking for something like a SIP to GSM gateway, but from my research it's not exactly something doable entirely in software in Android.

For example, there's [this question][1] I think is similar to what you're asking.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723453/android-as-sip-to-gsm-gateway

Comment: Phones are off topic

Comment: @DavidPostill but any potential solution isn't